# webpack compile a single entry point into multiple outputs based on DefinePlugin

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I currently have webpack setup to compile using `babel-loader`a single entry point into a single output bundle. Something like

`entry.js`

```
import { A } from "a.js"
import { B } from "b.js"
...
if (TEST) {
    console.log("this is a test");
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        entry: "entry.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/output"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/
            use: {
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            TEST: JSON.stringify(true)
        })
    ]
}
```

currently this all works fine. What I want though is the ability to create two versions of the `entry.bundle.js`. Effectively a version where `TEST` is true and a version where it is false: `entry.bundle.js` and `entry.test.bundle.js`

What do i need to change to achieve that? Ideally I would prefer not to have to have multiple webpack config files

Comment: Do you want to build them both at the same time? Or is one of these builds like a dev build vs a prod build? We have something similar going on where a gulp task run webpack with different configs based on the task name. I know it's not exactly what you're looking for, but I think it's pretty standard.

Comment: at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the boolean in this file, why not just if/else the file name and pass that same boolean down to the plugin?

```
let TEST = true; // assume this is passed in somehow, perhaps via cli arguments

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    entry: 'entry.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: TEST ? '[name].test.bundle.js' : '[name].bundle.js'
    path: __dirname + '/output'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader'
      }
    }]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      TEST: JSON.stringify(TEST) // variable, will be consistent with filename
    })
  ]
}
```

I do understand what you wish to do, but I am unaware of a slicker way to do this through any webpack specific techniques.

Comment: well, there will be more booleans. What im trying to do is to set up A/B tests and not have compile bundles to have code for each other

Comment: Does this not work for you then? I am not fully understanding your final expectation. Can you please clarify your question more as to exactly what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I'll update the question. but essentially i was wondering if there was a way to auto build two versions, one with TEST being true and one with it being false. Without having to have two webpack configs

Comment: ohh i see, i think i didnt read your answer properly. Let me think about it and this is probably what i need. Thanks!

Comment: @WindowsMaker Yea essentially you'll specify the flag, whether test or not, and you'll get the correct bundle with the file name. If there are multiple flags, you can always use a `case` statement to modify the file name. Cool, keep me posted with your findings!

Comment: @WindowsMaker any update on this? I'd like to help you solve it before your bounty expires

Comment: sorry, i just marked your answer as accepted :) i think it's very close to what i need and it has helped me rethink my problem. For anyone else running into this problem, this is definitely the solution :) thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to hear you were able to solve this or in the least get on the right track. Happy coding! :)